# How can I lookup dns service records in consul in python?

Tags: python, dns, service-discovery, consul

I am using [consul](http://www.consul.io/) to discover services in my environment. Consul's DNS service is running on a non-standard DNS port. My current solution is more of a work around and I would like to find the more pythonic way to do this:

```
digcmd='dig @127.0.0.1 -p 8600 chef.service.consul +short' # lookup the local chef server via consul
proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(digcmd),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err=proc.communicate()
chef_server = "https://"+out.strip('\n')
```

Comment: `dig` seems to be a robust way of doing this. Sometimes unixy is better than pythonic maybe?

Comment: I am open to that possibility :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [dnspython](http://www.dnspython.org/) library to make queries using python.

```
from dns import resolver

consul_resolver = resolver.Resolver()
consul_resolver.port = 8600
consul_resolver.nameservers = ["127.0.0.1"]

answer = consul_resolver.query("chef.service.consul", 'A')
for answer_ip in answer:
    print(answer_ip)
```

Using libraries like dnspython is more robust than invoking dig in a subprocess, because creating processes has memory and performance effects.

Answer (score 2):

It's also quite easy to call the HTTP API with [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html):

```
import urllib.request

answer = urllib.request.urlopen("http://localhost:8500/v1/catalog/service/chef").read()
```

The basics of the HTTP API are documented in the [Services Guide](http://www.consul.io/intro/getting-started/services.html).